# Best Practice - Implementing interface as a plugin

Tags: java, factory-pattern

This is a theorical question about programming patterns for an Open Source software project.

We are forking the Open Source project [Araword](http://sourceforge.net/projects/araword/) (written in Java, but that's partially relevant), we want to add the offline Text-To-Speech feature, as now it's only using Google's online TTS.

The software runs cross-platformly. So according to the underlying OS the user has to be able to choose between his platform-related TTS implementation or the cross-platform (Google) one.

We want to switch between every TTS implementation in an elegant manner, but what are the best practices about.

1) I've heard about Factory Method Pattern on wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

2) IoC / Service location pattern:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Maybe the [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). I think this is kind of off-topic since it's opinion-based. There's no one true answer.

Comment: Check out [Martin Fowler's article on Inversion of Control](http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html).  He's not a fan of Service Locator, and neither am I.  (Also, you might try [SE Programmer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) as a better place to get opinion based answers.)

Comment: @markspace opinion based questions are _very_ poor fit for Programmers - these tend be quickly voted down and closed over there, see http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6491#6491 Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to switch to the system's TTS, than do something like this:

1. Create a single class to manage the TTS systems
2. Make the class check the OS, and then switch the TTS accordingly
3. Use the TTS class to dynamically use the system's TTS.

Or, use the cross-platform FreeTTS library, and then implement that (Please note the voices are lower-quality).

The FreeTTS project can be found here:

http://freetts.sourceforge.net/docs/index.php